# Full Calendar não respeita data de fim

Tags: php, json, fullcalendar

Criei uma agenda com utilizando Full Calendar, ela exibe os eventos, porém não respeita a data de fim, sempre termina o evento um dia antes, mas apenas na exibição. Eu não sei se esse campo *duration* está sendo respeitado, mas deveria respeitar o campo *end*. Segue abaixo código que faz a busca e monta o json:

```
$conexao = new PDO('', '', '');
  if(!$conexao){
  echo "<script> window.location.replace('../erro.html'); </script>"; 
}

$consulta = $conexao->query("SELECT id, title, start, end, datediff(ADDDATE( end, INTERVAL 1 DAY), start) as duration FROM eventos");
    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
        $vetor[] = $linha;        
     }
    //Passando vetor em forma de json
    echo json_encode($vetor);
```

Agradeço se alguém tiver alguma sugestão de como solucionar.

js:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {  

            //CARREGA CALENDÁRIO E EVENTOS DO BANCO
            $('#calendario').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    right: 'prev,next',
                    center: 'title',
                    left: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                //defaultDate: '2016-01-12',
                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, 
                events: 'eventos.php',           
                eventColor: '#0277BD'
            }); 
    }); 

    </script>
```

Comment: No json os dados retornados respeitam a data de fim?

Comment: Sim, os dados estão corretos, mas na hora de exibir não funciona, sempre termina um dia antes. A data de início fica ok, só a de fim que não respeita. Tentei usar o campo o campo `duration`, mas ele também não respeita.

Comment: No seu select você não pode utilizar o `Between` para pegar informações entre as duas datas?

Comment: Tem como vc colocar o trecho do js q gera o fullcalendar? Pq se o json está correto o erro tá no js.

Comment: Poderia colocar o JSON que o PHP gera para que possamos replicar seu código?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se você olhar na [documentação](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/) verá que o ultimo dia (end) é **EXCLUSIVE** o que quer dizer que o dia do fim não conta. Por exemplo se o seu evento termina segunda, a data do fim deve ser terça as 00:00.00 para que segunda seja contado.

O END é o momento imediatamente após o evento ter terminado.

Comment: Ok, vou tentar adicionar um dia na data mesmo e não no tempo de duração, pois não está funcionando

Comment: Olha parece ser uma medida paliativa mas não é, é assim que funciona. Vou até colocar uma frase da documentação na resposta

Comment: Fiz como citei, adicionei um dia a mais na data final, deu certo. Obrigada pela dica!